# I am getting error while calling functions inside mapped array in React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, express

Actually I am calling function by mapping over array

```
let artistId = artist._id;
orderData.products.map((cartproduct, index) => {
const sendOrderData = {
        product: cartproduct._id,
        qty: cartproduct.qty,
      };
  createOrder(userId, sendOrderData).then((data) => {
         if(data.error){
            console.log(data.error)
            }else{
           updateOrderDetails(artistId,sendData).then((response) => {
                if(response.error){
                    console.log(response.error)
                   }else{
                    console.log("done)
                  }
})
```

But before updateOrderDetails function call is completed for first element the createorder function is called for next element and thus I am not able to update data adequately.

UpdateOrderDetails makes an API call:

```
export const updateOrderDetailsOfArtist = (artistId, data) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/artist/updateorderdetails/${artistId}`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: Maybe use `await` ?

Comment: How do i use that can you please send me example

Comment: `await updateOrderDetails(artistId)...`

Comment: And where should i place async?

Answer (score 0):

So, where ever you have the `updateOrderDetails(artistId)` function written,
add `async` to it.

```
async function updateOrderDetails(artistId) {
...
// where ever you're using the return statement type await
return await response
}
```

But for a better answer you need to show what the updateOrderDetails function does, what does it return, what API calls it is doing.

Comment: This didn't worked out

Comment: Can you show us more of your code?

Comment: Actually i got it solved using conditionally making request to updateorderdeatils